# Travis conditional sudo by branch

Tags: travis-ci

Using Travis, I am automating the Docker build on every push to `abc123` branch.

In order to make Docker run there, Travis needs `sudo: required` for the [virtualization setup](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Virtualization-environments)

It works for every branch, but using a container based build has another advantages (like speed, for example), and I would like to run the build with `sudo: false` on every branch that is not `abc123`.

Is it possible to have a `sudo` configuration for a specific branch in Travis?

Comment: You can probably use the [build matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Build-Matrix) to do that. Probably.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment-variable `TRAVIS_SUDO` to differntiate between the two versions.

The current version of their docs has this included:

> `TRAVIS_SUDO`: `true` or `false` based on whether `sudo` is enabled.

Source: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables

---

Another solution would be to have different `.travis.yml` in different branches, but merging back and forth can make this difficult to maintain.

Comment: The TRAVIS_SUDO envvar is the opposite of what they want. It tells you what the sudo status _is_, but it doesn't let you set it based on branch.

Comment: correct. I would have my build-script behave differently depending on that envvar.

Comment: the sudo entry in travis.yml files can't be dynamically set based on that envvar, unfortunately. That was the point of this question.